# Python lambda parameters

Tags: python, lambda

I have the following code:

```
g = lambda a, b, c: sum(a, b, c)
print g([4,6,7])
```

How do I get the lambda function to expand the list into 3 values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expand the list t0 3 values can be done by this:

```
 g(*[4,6,7])
```

But the `sum` won't work in your way.
Or you can write this way:

```
>>> g = lambda *arg: sum(arg)
>>> print g(4, 5, 6)
15
>>>
```

Or just make your lambda accept a list:

```
g = lambda alist: sum(alist)
print g([4,6,7])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
g = lambda L: sum(L)
print g([4,6,7])
```

would work for any arbitrarily sized list.

If you want to use `g = lambda a, b, c: someFunc(a, b, c)`, then call `print g(4,6,7)`

Comment: You answer is wrong, the `sum` can not accept there arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you change `lambda` to take a list. Because `sum()` doesn't take three arguments:

```
>>> g = lambda a_list: sum(a_list)
>>> print g([4,6,7])
17
```

or a non-keyword argument:

```
>>> g = lambda *nkwargs: sum(nkwargs)
>>> print g(4,6,7)
17
```

Answer (score 1):

You're defining a function which takes three parameters, and the supplying it with a single parameter, a list. 
If you want

```
print g([4,6,7])
```

to work, your definition should be

```
g = lambda lst: sum(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you are looking for is:

```
>>> g = lambda a, b, c: sum([a, b, c])
>>> print g(*[4,6,7])
17
```

What you were trying to do **wont work:**

```
>>> g = lambda a, b, c: sum(a, b, c)
>>> print g(*[4,6,7])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#83>", line 1, in <module>
    print g(*[4,6,7])
  File "<pyshell#82>", line 1, in <lambda>
    g = lambda a, b, c: sum(a, b, c)
TypeError: sum expected at most 2 arguments, got 3
```

Because `sum()` can't handle the arguments you gave it.

---

Since your lambda function is simply a `sum()` function, why not just call `sum()` directly?

If your code the following `a, b, c` values:

```
>>> a, b, c = range(1,4)
>>> print a,b,c
1 2 3
```

And you wanted to do:

```
>>> g = lambda a, b, c: sum([a, b, c])
>>> print g(*[a,b,c])
6
```

Why not just do the following?:

```
>>> sum([a,b,c])
6
```

Comment: This is an example, I am trying to do something else but the lambda parameters are what I wanted to know about.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> g=lambda *l: sum(l)
>>> print g(1,2,3)
6
```

Answer (score 1):

If your lambda expects to have a list/tuple of fixed length passed in, but wants to expand the values in that list/tuple into separate parameter variables, the following will work.

```
g = lambda (a, b, c): a + b + c
g([4, 6, 7])
```

Note the parentheses around the parameter list.

This "feature" works in Python 2.x, but was removed in Python 3